# Is joining tables is better than putting the string of the other table directly?

Tags: mysql, sql

Form example lets say i have two tables

```
      users                     posts
[ id  -  username ]    [ id  -  username  -   content ]
[ 1   -   AXBAXBA ]    [ 1   -   AXBAXBA  -  contentA ]
[ 2   -   AXAAXAA ]    [ 2   -   AXAAXAA  -  contentB ]
[ 3   -   AXDAXDA ]    [ 3   -   AXDAXDA  -  contentC ]
```

Is this design is better? Since i'm going to use only one query quickly

`SELECT username, content FROM posts`

OR is it bettter to go with this tables design for joining

```
      users                     posts
[ id  -  username ]    [ id  -  userid  -   content ]
[ 1   -   AXBAXBA ]    [ 1   -     1    -  contentA ]
[ 2   -   AXAAXAA ]    [ 2   -     2    -  contentB ]
[ 3   -   AXDAXDA ]    [ 3   -     3    -  contentC ]
```

then go with the joining query

`SELECT a.username, b.content FROM users a LEFT JOIN posts b ON a.id = b.userid`

Which Design is better and Why?

Comment: If its a OneToOne relation keep details in same table

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid How `OneToOne` exactly?

Comment: If each user has single content record or other details keep in one table, If a single user can have many records then go for ManyToMany approach by adding new table

Comment: Check out the Stack Overflow schema for ideas: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/366696

Comment: It depends on how you want to handle things like name changes.

Comment: There are pros's cons to each.  Lets say user AXBAXBA changes their name.  now we have to update the user and posts.  better to use the ID.  but then lets say user AXDAXDA decides they want their account deleted.  Do you delete the posts?  no?  then who posted it?  by keeping the name you have the history.  So what is it that you want?

Comment: I see a vote to close this question as "primarily opinion-based." IMO, that's being overly strict about Stack Overflow guidelines. There are pros and cons to most code design decisions. It's a legitimate question to ask about the pros and cons.

Comment: That's my vote.  Given that's it's still the only vote, it's a minority opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is only a 1 to 1 relationship between [users] and [posts], then just use one table (id, username, content). If a single user can have multiple contents, then the latter design is the way to go. That way, you can store the user information in one place, and if you need to do something like change user #1's username, you just have to update [users].

Comment: So using multiple tables is good fo ease of use, Since i'll only need to change one record at `users` table to change the others too, Is that the only advantage? Or adding same username multiple times is bad for the size of table too?

Comment: Unless you are dealing with a lot of data (an amount I have never encountered and I don't think 90% of folks will even encounter), table size is not going to be an issue given this scenario. I guess you could think of it as easier, but really it's about maintenance. It just makes sense to most people that if some user attribute changes, then you should only change one row. Also, it avoids situations where you can update UserName in TableB for one row of user #1, but forget to update all rows for user #1.

Comment: +1 the advantage to updating the username in one place gets even more important if you have multiple tables that reference it. User favorites, user payments, user friends, etc. If you have to update multiple tables to handle a username change, it gets expensive and complex. Treat the username as an *attribute* of the user, and use a numeric ID as the PK. The user should never need or want to change an arbitrary numeric ID.

Answer (score 2):

The latter suggestion is better. Strings take up a larger amount of storage space than integers do. If you can relate a your tables with integers instead of strings, do it.

Just a warning, having columns named 'id' in both tables could lead to some confusion when operating on them. I think it would be best to name the 'id' column in the posts table 'postid'. Just my two cents.

Comment: I prefer ID personally  The table name tells me which Id.  and if all tables PK is ID; ir really don't have to think much. and if the FK is always tableNameID then I know the foreign keys pretty well too.  but I do alias to TableNameID when displaying the IDs.

Comment: There are always exceptions... you can't just use TableNameID in every case, because you might have more than one column that references the table. For example: `Bugs.ReportedByUserId` and `Bugs.AssignedToUserId`

Answer (score 2):

Joins always make your query much faster rather joining queries to get the result. If your query is returning small data go for query concatenation if the results are large go for joins.